# admin-on-rest - ImageField isn't displaying image from rest client api

Tags: rest, reactjs, imagefield, admin-on-rest

I am unable to get the `ImageField` component (https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Fields.html#imagefield) to render any type of image. Take http://lorempixel.com/628/1837/transport/10 for example, I include it inside the component as source but it doesn't display anything back. Below is some of my sample code, including my API return call that's also trying to render an image in 64bit. Both the API call image, and the lorempixel image returns nothing back:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  FormTab,
  ImageField,
  TabbedForm
} from 'admin-on-rest';

export const AcceptedEdit = (props) => {
  return (
    <Edit title={<AcceptedTitle />} {...props}>
      <TabbedForm>
        <FormTab label="status">
          <ImageField source="json.photos.idPhoto.data" title="picture.title" />
          <ImageField source="photos.idPhoto.data" title="picture.title" />
          <ImageField source="http://lorempixel.com/628/1837/transport/10" title="picture.title" />
        </FormTab>
      </TabbedForm>
    </Edit>
  )
};
```

And below is the return of my api call:

```
{
  "photos": {
    "address": "tyaWSJpUGy1BQvYMk3GYBgigQVEorRz5Fg",
    "idPhoto": {
      "contentType": "image/jpeg",
      "data": "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"
    }
  }
}
```

And lastly, if it's useful, this is the html (from chrome inspector) generated by the component:

```
<span></span>
    <div class="aor-input-photos.idPhoto.data">
        <span></span>
        <div>
            <span></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="aor-input-http://lorempixel.com/628/1837/transport/10">
        <span></span>
        <div>
            <span></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="aor-input-url">
        <span></span>
        <div>
            <span></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="aor-input-http://lorempixel.com/628/1837/transport/10.url">
        <span></span>
        <div>
            <span></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="aor-input-json.photos.idPhoto.data.url">
        <span></span>
        <div>
            <span></span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: It seems that the record inside ImageField is using the GET_ALL api call, which doesn't include images. But I have written a GET_ONE api call inside my rest client, and when I console.log it out, the response is the one that I need for images inside the Edit component.

So I'm wondering why the record value inside ImageField doesn't use the GET_ONE api call... is there a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, ImageField does not accept an image url directly so the lorempixel example will not work. This is because ImageField is meant to be used with a resource, otherwise, just use a good old img tag.

The ImageField cannot display your image most probably because it expect a valid src. If you want your base64 image to be displayed, prefix its value with `data:image/png;base64,` (at the API level) and it should work.

For example: if you enter your base64 string directly in your browser adress bar, it won't display anything.

But you should be able to paste the following and it will display your image (at least in chrome):

`data:image/png;base64,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`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I managed to get some dummy data loaded using your suggestion. 

It seems my API call for GET_ONE is buggy, so I'll look into that now